# Add in another For Loop in order to have another worksheets data added before the file is saved

Tags: excel, vba

I have a script that processes a master file and creates a report per manager. In column A, all rows under mgr 1 are stored and printed to a template, and then it loops through all managers until the data ends.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
  Dim Wb As Workbook
  Dim Data, Last
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, a As Long
  Dim Dest As Range

  'Refer to the template
  Set Wb = Workbooks("SpecializedSkillsTemplate.xlsx")
  'Refer to the destination cell
  Set Dest = Wb.Sheets("Manager Summary").Range("B1")
  'Read in all data
  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet7")
    Data = .Range("Z2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
  End With
  Wb.Activate


  'Process the data
  For i = 1 To UBound(Data)
    'Manager changes?
    If Data(i, 1) <> Last Then
      'Skip the first
      If i > 1 Then
        'Scroll into the view
        Dest.Select
        'Save a copy
        Wb.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & _
          ValidFileName(Last & "_Assessment.xlsx")
      End If
      'Clear the employees
      Dest.Resize(, Columns.Count - Dest.Column).EntireColumn.ClearContents
      'Remember this manager
      Last = Data(i, 1)
      'Start the next round
      j = 0
    End If
    'Write the employee data into the template
    a = 0
    For k = 2 To UBound(Data, 2)
      Dest.Offset(a, j) = Data(i, k)
      a = a + 1
    Next

    'Next column
    j = j + 1
  Next
End Sub
```

It takes the data from `sheet 7` in the master file, but is it possible to have another `For/Next` loop that does this for another sheet? Say I have `sheet 8` and I want it to do the same thing and take that employee data and transpose offset it by a column, so I can compare the two sets. Is this possible?

I was thinking of adding something like:

```
Dim Data2 

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet8")
    Data2 = .Range("Z2, . Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With
```

and then another `For/Next` Loop:

```
For x = 1 to UBound(Data2)
    If Data2(I,1) <> Last
Next
```

etc. Can anyone let me know if this is feasible?

Comment: You want to accomplish the same thing on "Sheet8" that you accomplished on "Sheet7"?

Comment: yes, and then paste that `sheet 8` data as an offset, so +2 columns over from the `sheet 7` data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Variantly Integrating For Next Loop

### The Tasks

I've added 6 lines and modified one (marked with '*** in the code.

> - Added string constant that will hold sheet names.
> - Added variant where the sheet names will be put into and read from.
> - Added counter for looping through sheet names in variant.
> - Using the split function pasted data from string into variant (array).
> - Started For Next Loop.
> - Modified ThisWorkbook.Sheets().
> - Closed For Next Loop.

### The Code

```
Option Explicit

    Sub Main()

      Const cStrSheet As String = "Sheet7,Sheet8,Sheet9" '***

      Dim vntSheet As Variant ' ***
      Dim iSheet As Integer ' ***

      Dim Wb As Workbook
      Dim Data, Last
      Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, a As Long
      Dim Dest As Range

      'Refer to the template
      Set Wb = Workbooks("SpecializedSkillsTemplate.xlsx")
      'Refer to the destination cell
      Set Dest = Wb.Sheets("Manager Summary").Range("B1")

      vntSheet = Split(cStrSheet, ",") '***

      For iSheet = 0 To UBound(vntSheet) '***

        'Read in all data
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(vntSheet(iSheet)) '***
          Data = .Range("Z2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        End With
        Wb.Activate

        'Process the data
        For i = 1 To UBound(Data)
          'Manager changes?
          If Data(i, 1) <> Last Then
            'Skip the first
            If i > 1 Then
              'Scroll into the view
              Dest.Select
              'Save a copy
              Wb.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & _
                ValidFileName(Last & "_Assessment.xlsx")
            End If
            'Clear the employees
            Dest.Resize(, Columns.Count - Dest.Column).EntireColumn.ClearContents
            'Remember this manager
            Last = Data(i, 1)
            'Start the next round
            j = 0
          End If
          'Write the employee data into the template
          a = 0
          For k = 2 To UBound(Data, 2)
            Dest.Offset(a, j) = Data(i, k)
            a = a + 1
          Next

          'Next column
          j = j + 1
        Next

      Next ' iSheet '***

    End Sub
```

Comment: on a side note, when I run the original script, it stops on the last set of data in the template. Is there a reason why it doesn't loop through that and save it off too?

Comment: Can you tell me what line exactly and what the error message is? I don't know what your code does, I offered just the implementation i.e. whatever it does to one sheet, it'll do to the other. But if you have some pasting outside the worksheet you should adjust e.g. if you were pasting into a 2 column of another worksheet you have to adjust the iSheet variable so that for the first sheet it pastes into the 2 column as before so instead of 2 u use 2+iSheet if you want to paste into the next column etc.

Comment: The array is 0-based i.e. the first loop will be 0, the next 1 etc. So I've seen in the comments that you're talking about 2 columns over which would mean you should add to the column number +2*iSheet so the first time the column would be column+2*0 and the second time it would be column+2*1. And there are 3 sheets in the array, maybe you're using only 2?